# Loop and/or if else double return

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I am attempting to write a program that plays a dice game with the user betting high low or sevens. So far I have successfully gotten the dice roll and adding part correct, my betting function is not going well. Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project07
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random r = new Random();
    int money = 100;
    int newtotal = 100;
    System.out.println("You have " + money + " dollars");
    while (money > 0)
    {
      System.out.println("Enter an amount to be or 0 to quit");
      int bet = keyboard.nextInt();
      if (bet == 0)
      {
        System.out.println("You end with " + money + " dollars");
        System.exit(0);
      }

      System.out.println("Bet 1 for high, 2 for low, or 3 for 7's");
      int choose = keyboard.nextInt();
      int diceb = r.nextInt(7 - 1) + 1;
      int dicea = r.nextInt(7 - 1) + 1;
      int dicetotal = dicea + diceb;
      System.out.println(dicetotal);
      System.out.println("You bet $" + bet);
      if ((choose == 1) && (dicetotal > 7))
      {
        newtotal = newtotal + bet;
        System.out.println("You win $" + bet);
        System.out.print("You have " + newtotal + " dollars left");
      }
      else if ((choose == 1) && (dicetotal <= 7))
      {
        newtotal = newtotal - bet;
        System.out.println("You have " + newtotal + "dollars left");
      }
      else if ((choose == 2) && (dicetotal < 7))
      {
        newtotal = newtotal + bet;
        System.out.println("You have " + newtotal + "dollars left");
      }
      else if ((choose == 2) && (dicetotal >= 7))
      {
        newtotal = newtotal - bet;
        System.out.println("You have " + newtotal + "dollars left");
      }
      else if ((choose == 3) && (dicetotal == 7))
      {
        newtotal = newtotal + bet;
        System.out.println("You have " + newtotal + "dollars left");
      }
      else if ((choose == 3) && (dicetotal != 7))
        ;
      {
        newtotal = newtotal - bet;
        System.out.println("You have " + newtotal + "dollars left");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output I get should be something such as: You have 100 dollars
Enter an amount to be or 0 to quit
20
Bet 1 for high, 2 for low, or 3 for 7's
1
11
You bet $20
You win $20
You have 120 dollars left
Enter an amount to be or 0 to quit
0
You end with 120 dollars

However it seems to activate both the winning and losing parts of the if else block and give me this:You have 100 dollars
Enter an amount to be or 0 to quit
20
Bet 1 for high, 2 for low, or 3 for 7's
1
11
You bet $20
You win $20
You have 120 dollars leftYou have 100dollars left
Enter an amount to be or 0 to quit
0
You end with 100 dollars

Not quite sure where my problem is, maybe I need to write a new method specifically for the bet function of it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please format your if statements normally.

Comment: There's a `;` at the last `if else` condition, which means that the last expected `if else` condition will always run. Also close your scanner object in the end to prevent memory leak.

Comment: Following some kind of formatting convention will help you catch simple mistake like that.

Comment: The editor you have almost certainly has an option of some sort to auto-format the source.  Use it.  Glomming code together is *not* being "efficient" -- it leads to all sorts of errors.

Comment: Thanks guys sorry for my messy code I'm just starting out on this programming stuff so I'm not too sure what standard formatting is supposed to look like.

Comment: Also to make it better formated, put common denominators outside in new if statements e.g. if(choose == 3){ if(dicetotal == 7){} else{}}... Makes it much more readable.

Comment: @awfullyawesome thanks for the formatting help and the advice on the if else condition that was a huge help!!

Comment: @user3250642: That's the point of the SO community. ;) Glad we could be of help. :)

Answer (score 3):

Properly formatted (one of 2 major styles):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random r = new Random();
    int money = 100;
    int newtotal = 100;
    System.out.println("You have " + money + " dollars");
    while (money > 0) {
        System.out.println("Enter an amount to be or 0 to quit");
        int bet = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (bet == 0) {
            System.out.println("You end with " + money +" dollars");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Bet 1 for high, 2 for low, or 3 for 7's");
        int choose = keyboard.nextInt();
        int diceb = r.nextInt(7 - 1) + 1;
        int dicea = r.nextInt(7 - 1) + 1;
        int dicetotal = dicea + diceb;
        System.out.println(dicetotal);
        System.out.println("You bet $" + bet);
        if ((choose == 1) && (dicetotal >7)) {
            newtotal= newtotal + bet; 
            System.out.println("You win $" + bet); 
            System.out.print("You have " + newtotal +" dollars left");
        }
        else if ((choose == 1) && (dicetotal <= 7)) { 
            newtotal = newtotal - bet; 
            System.out.println("You have " + newtotal + "dollars left"); 
        }
        else if ((choose == 2) && (dicetotal < 7)) {
            newtotal = newtotal + bet; 
            System.out.println("You have " + newtotal  + "dollars left");
        }
        else if ((choose == 2) && (dicetotal >= 7)) {
            newtotal = newtotal - bet; 
            System.out.println("You have " + newtotal  + "dollars left");
        }
        else if ((choose == 3) && (dicetotal == 7)) {
            newtotal = newtotal + bet; 
            System.out.println("You have " + newtotal + "dollars left");
        }
        else if ((choose == 3) && (dicetotal != 7)); { <<== Wayward semicolon!!
            newtotal = newtotal - bet; 
            System.out.println("You have " + newtotal  + "dollars left");
        }
    }
}
```

The wayward semicolon would be obvious, since you're never place a semicolon anywhere other than at the end of a line.  It's easy to glance down the code and see the `if` conditions -- you don't have to dig them out of the clutter.  Where the `while` ends is obvious from indentation.

(The other major style is to place the `{` characters on their own lines:

```
        ...
        }
        else if ((choose == 1) && (dicetotal <= 7))
        { 
            newtotal = newtotal - bet; 
            System.out.println("You have " + newtotal + "dollars left"); 
        }
        else if ((choose == 2) && (dicetotal < 7))
        {
            newtotal = newtotal + bet; 
            System.out.println("You have " + newtotal  + "dollars left");
        }
        ...
```

I'm not as fond of this style both because it spreads out the text too much (and screen space is valuable when trying to read & understand a large program) and because, with the wayward `;` case, it's not as obvious that the `;` is out of place.)

(There is also a style that places the closing `}` on the same line as a following `else`:

```
        ...
        } else if ((choose == 1) && (dicetotal <= 7)) { 
            newtotal = newtotal - bet; 
            System.out.println("You have " + newtotal + "dollars left"); 
        } else if ((choose == 2) && (dicetotal < 7)) {
        ...
```

This is more compact, but to my eye TOO compact, and starting to be cluttered.  Plus it makes it impossible to place a comment line just ahead of the `else`.  But others have different preferences.  Mainly pick one style and stick with it, and in a team try to agree to a common scheme (without being oppressive about it).)